# How to verify if AWS SES API requests are signed using Signature Version 4

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

An email from Amazon AWS states:

> Beginning October 1st, 2020, Amazon SES will only support requests
> signed using Signature Version 4.
>
> You can easily identify API requests that use Signature Version 3 by
> looking at the request headers. Requests that use the Signature
> Version 3 resemble the following example: X-Amzn-Authorization:
> AWS3-HTTPS
> AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE,Algorithm=HMACSHA256,Signature=lBP67vCvGl
> ...

I have got "aws/aws-sdk-php" installed through composer.
I'm trying to find out if the request header of SES is Signature Version 3 or 4.

I tried dumping the content of `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent`  through `$event->message->getHeader()` which is a `Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderSet` Object.
Yet it doesn't include the request version to the SES sdk.

**QUESTION:**
Could someone please tell me how to dump the outgoing aws ses sdk request so I can see in the header what version is used.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, finally was able to do it by back tracing the stack.
After sending a mail through a command, I back traced the stack and could see the raw request, which included `Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA25`, confirming Signature Version 4.

```
Mail::to($receiver)->send($mailable);
dump(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 50));
```

Make sure that you have the ses service debug set to true:
`config/services.php`

```
   'ses' => [
        'key'    => env('SES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
        'region' => 'us-west-1',
        'debug'  => true,
    ],
```

Comment: I have to check same but on ruby on rails do you know how to check in ruby @MPS

Comment: @sunil I'm not familiar with Ruby, sorry.  If you can't find an answer here on StackExchange, maybe try asking in the Ruby Discord Server, I heard it's active.